# How to process string in Elasticsearch while indexing and store it against a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to index a document in Elasticsearch. In document i have a field and value like `"mon": "00:00@#24:00@#AA^00:00@#24:00@#BB"`, what i am trying to do is while indexing i want to parse this and store it in elasticsearch like

```
"mon": [
  {
     "open_hrs": "00:00",
     "close_hrs": "24:00",
     "hrs_type": "AA"
  },
  {
     "open_hrs": "00:00",
     "close_hrs": "24:00",
     "hrs_type": "BB"
  }]
```

Is it possible in Elasticsearch at time of indexing and how to do it at time of indexing a document in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Combine `Pattern capture Token Filter` and `copy_to` syntax. You should copy you'r field in different fields and set a `custom analyzer` for each field which extracts the desired part using appropriate regex.
What do you want to do with `mon` field? depending the case it should be defined as 'nested' or `object'.